# C Programming: Segmentation fault at struct ptr. Memory alloc issue

Tags: c, caching, segmentation-fault

I am getting segfault during runtime at:

I am trying to build this cache memory model in C.

So, the code compiles fine but I am getting segfault during runtime.
I tracked it down to this line:

`cache->set[i]->block = (Block *) malloc( cache->numSets * sizeof( Block ) );`

I tried making Block as an array inside of Set struct. But that gives other issues and infact gives the same segmentation fault as well.

```
typedef struct CacheMemory* Cache;
typedef struct Set_* Set;
typedef struct Block_* Block;

struct Block_ {
    int valid;
    int tag; // int *tag;
    int dirty;
};

struct Set_ {
    int numBlocks;
    Block *block;
};

struct CacheMemory {
  <snip>
  Set *set;
};

Cache cache;
cache = (Cache) malloc(sizeof ( struct CacheMemory ) );

cache->set = (Set *) malloc( numSets * sizeof( Set ) );

    for (i=0; i<cache->numSets; i++) {
           //for (j = 0; j < cache->blockSize; j=j+1) {
                // Note: I get segfault at line below during runtime
                cache->set[i]->block = (Block *) malloc( cache->numSets *sizeof( Block ) );
                    //cache->set[i]->block[j] = (Block_) malloc (sizeof(Block_) );
       // }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you use a debugger to track the segmenation fault? Did you inspect the variables involved? Which value was stored in `i`?

Comment: In your for loop: `for (i=0; i<cache->numSets; i++) {`, the value of `cache->numSets` is not set.

Comment: You are using `numSets` in the `malloc` but you are using `cache->numSets` in the loop condition clause. The latter is probably not set correctly (e.g.) After the `malloc`, do: `cache->numSets = numSets;`

Comment: Your code mighe be an example why you should not hide pointer types in a `typedef`

Comment: Are you aware that `cache->set` is of type pointer to pointer to `struct Set_`?

Comment: I pasted only snippets of code. Actual code is pretty large. I dont believe the value of numSets is actually an issue. i have tried fixed values etc. I am aware that cache->set is a pointer to pointer. There are multiple sets in a cache, so that was the reasoning behind it.

Comment: if someone cannot replicate the error with your current posted "snippets" then you might want to consider updating your code by editing your question. This is aloud and helps finding the error faster by others. Question send from "question triage" to "requires editing". Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you fix. it.

Comment: having these statements: `typedef struct CacheMemory* Cache;
typedef struct Set_* Set;
typedef struct Block_* Block;` before the definition of the struct's is a problem.  They should be after the struct definitions

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `cache = (Cache) malloc(sizeof ( struct CacheMemory ) );`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer,  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. 2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror()` with your error message.  The result is both your error message and the reason the system thinks the error occurred will be output to `stderr`, as they should be

Comment: do not hide pointers in `typedef` statements.  This (poor) activity makes the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is a pointer to `struct Set_`, so your malloc

```
cache->set = (Set *) malloc( numSets * sizeof( Set ) );
```

reserves pointers, not `struct Set_`-objects.
Rewriting it as

```
cache->set = (Set *) malloc( numSets * sizeof( struct Set_ ) );
```

should help at least around this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately `cache->set` is of type `Set*`, not `struct Set_`.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: `typedef struct CacheMemory* Cache;`
`typedef struct Set_ Set;  // changed from Set_ *Set;`
`typedef struct Block_ Block; // changed from Block_ Block;`  and in the malloc changed it to count for size of struct Set_ ( `cache->set = (Set *) malloc( numSets * sizeof( Set_ ) );` )   That seem to fix the problem. Getting segfault in another area. Will update this soon Thanks for all your help.